# jquery: closest('h3') selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, closest

i have:

```
<ul class="rating">
    <h3>Like this</h3>
    <li class="rating-number">
        <div id="iLikeThis" class="iLikeThis">
            <span class="counter">2</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this is my jquery code

```
$('.iLikeThis .counter').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('h3').text('You like this');
        $(this).parent().addClass('like');
});
```

Is there a better way to select the nearest h3 element. It does work with 3-times parent() but not with closest('h3).

Why?

Comment: This is invalid HTML. You can't have a `h3` as a child of a `ul`. With  broken HTML like this, it's impossible to know if the browser does the right thing.

Comment: thanks! can you have it as a child of li?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As `h3` is not a parent of `.counter`, that won't work. Use `.closest()` on `.rating` instead and find its `h3`:

```
$(this).closest('.rating').children('h3').text('You like this');
```